# For loop with append and array issue

Tags: python

How to make append multiple times in for loop to get same results for B like below

```
import numpy as np

B1 = np.linspace(0,1,7)
B2 = np.linspace(3,8,7)

B = np.append(B1, B2)

B = np.append(B, B2)
B = np.append(B, B2)
B = np.append(B, B2)
B = np.append(B, B2)
```

so far try something like this but i don't have anny ideas

```
n = 5 
for i in range(n):
    B[i] = np.append(B, B2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.tile()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to append multiple times along a certain axis.

```
B = np.append( B1, np.tile(B2, (1, 5)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 5 
for i in range(n):
    B = np.append(B, B2)
```

Comment: No need for brackets `[i]`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.